# How to clean up misaligned columns in text separated by spaces?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a file with below strings in it which are misaligned. I want to align this file properly so that each of the word in each line are properly spaced.

```
3 281 901.188.30.53 901001 1 poihelloswqs-1146414
3 598 901.189.166.233 901001 1 poihelloswqs-90877846
3 300 901.156.77.57 901001 1 poihelloswqs-90137229
3 263 901.156.17.80 901001 1 poihelloswqs-90135797
3 264 901.875.875.79 901001 1 poihelloswqs-1389375
3 265 901.189.153.234 901001 1 poihelloswqs-1568332
3 266 901.218.93.873 901001 1 poihelloswqs-3240561
3 268 901.158.76.23 901001 1 poihelloswqs-3242066
3 269 901.218.30.120 901001 1 poihelloswqs-3242532
```

It should output something like this: This way they all are properly aligned. Is this possible to do in Linux?

```
3 281 901.188.30.53     901001 1 poihelloswqs-1146414
3 598 901.189.166.233   901001 1 poihelloswqs-90877846
3 300 901.156.77.57     901001 1 poihelloswqs-90137229
3 263 901.156.17.80     901001 1 poihelloswqs-90135797
3 264 901.875.875.79    901001 1 poihelloswqs-1389375
3 265 901.189.153.234   901001 1 poihelloswqs-1568332
3 266 901.218.93.873    901001 1 poihelloswqs-3240561
3 268 901.158.76.23     901001 1 poihelloswqs-3242066
3 269 901.218.30.120    901001 1 poihelloswqs-3242532
```

Comment: Use `printf()` with fixed width fields.

Comment: Also see [Why is the “how to move the turtle in logo” question closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158289) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `column -t` is meant for this. it has switches to specify input separator, output separator, right-align certain columns, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very ugly but this may work:

```
cat xx | ruby -nle 'puts $_.split().join("\t")' |pr --expand-tabs -tT
```

You may need to replace the single `\t` with multiple tab characters if your columns vary greatly in width.

This is ruby splitting the line on any white space, then joining using tabs. Finally `pr` is replacing tabs with spaces (and the `-tT` avoids the annoying headers and pagination)

If you know the fields are separated by a single character `tr` can do the replacement easily:

```
 cat xx | tr ' ' "\t"  |pr --expand-tabs -tT
```

Comment: or with GNU sed `sed 's/ /\t/3' file` or `sed 's/ /\t/3' file | column -s $'\t' -t`

Comment: If I execute this `cat align.txt | ruby -nle 'puts $_.split().join("\t")' |pr --expand-tabs -tT|` command, then it gives me this line `>`. Below is the output I got:
`host:~$ cat align.txt | ruby -nle 'puts $_.split().join("\t")' |pr --expand-tabs -tT|
>`

Comment: @Cyrus I got a seg fault with your second command on my file. Not sure why?

Comment: @flash: Maybe a bug in the implementation of the `column` command you are using.